# printing an alert or some message when error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i want to print somekind of message or put an alert when the user fills the login form with wrong values this is what i have

```
const login  = dispatch => async ({ vCellphone, vPassword }) => {
    const response = await ForceApi.post('/LoginController.php', { vCellphone, vPassword });
    const Validar = response.data.error;
    const Mensaje = response.data.message;
    dispatch({ type: 'login', payload: response.data.id});
    if(Validar == false ){
        navigate('Panel');

        } else{console.log('algo');
        Alert.alert(
            'Alert Title',
            'My Alert Msg',
            [
              {text: 'Ask me later', onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')},
              {
                text: 'Cancel',
                onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
                style: 'cancel',
              },
              {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
            ],
            {cancelable: false},
          );
        } 
    };
```

the `if(Validar == false){ navigate}` is called when everything its ok and the user filled the form with the right informatiosn abd works very good, the trouble is when the user fills with the wrong information, the else does nothing

Answer (score 0):

since is a form validations what you trying to do i suggest to use the `<form>` tag. id you are using php the form could be like this:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

were the attribute `required` help to restrict the post-submit since there a is empty value for a input or you also can do it with `required` in react:

```
handleClick = e => {
    console.log('Button was clicked');
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Form was submitted');
    console.log(this.state);
  };
...
render() { 
return(
...
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input
              required
              onChange={this.props.onChange}
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              name="firstName"
              value={this.props.formValues.firstName}
            />
          </div>

          <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="btn btn-primary">
            Save
          </button>
        </form>
...
);
}
```

there are js ways to validate the information, but i prefer that the html do that part and use the html5 attributes.

Comment: not sure if this is going to work in the case where the user fill the form but fill it wrong

Comment: what u exactly means with wrong, since wrong can be for example a e-mail that's not a mail (in that case also exist html attributes) or wrong like the e-mail doesn't exist in DB?

Comment: i mean when the user insert an e-mail that doesnt exist on db

Comment: `if(Validar == false){ navigate}` works when `response.data.error` is equals to `-0, "", undefined, null, ` so are you sure that you are not return none of these values? how is the response when something went wrong?

Comment: the errors that i wisjt to print are like these 
`Object {
  "error": true,
  "message": "Error, Falta parametros.",
}<`